# Temporary blocking for push to mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration

I am trying to automate a ci process: some files commits by `ci-script` to `hg` repo `assets` on remote `Server`. The question is how to prevent push to repo `assets` for all user during my ci process? Otherwise two heads will be created and ci-script will not be able to push.

1. ci-script: pullup repo to branch B
2. user: commit to branch *B*
3. user: push
4. ci-script commit to branch *B*
5. ci-script can't push because of two heads with name *B*.

I have an idea: create temporary lock-file on the `Server` during ci-process and check its existence on prepush hook (it's probably a `preoutgoing`). But this solution requires an access for each repo user to the `Server`. Also all users must have correct prepush hooks.

Any ideas?

Comment: You sound like you rather want to use subversion than mercurial, if you want to disallow asynchronous work. However you should consider to use a server-side pretxnchangegroup to disallow new heads. However mind: new heads are nothing scary or wrong when using a DVCS.

Comment: @planetmaker, I want to disallow asynchronous work just temporally - while ci-script is working. Sometimes I am deals with many heads with the same name. It's ok for manual interaction, but not for automated si-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved partially by automatic `rebase` in ci-script.

Comment: What did it do, rebase the commit from the ci script on top of the latest user push?

Comment: @StayOnTarget yes, script tried to rebase his changes before push